# Get json string name from json variables using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need a way to get the title/name of an array, just by detecting the values inside of that array in Javascript.

I have an json array where there are the arrays of `greeting` and `food`. The variable `x` is equal to `hi` and the variable `y` is equal to `pizza`.

```js
    var $arrays = {greeting: ['hello', 'hi'], food: ['pizza', 'cookie']};
    var x = 'hi',
        y = 'pizza';
```

I need to now return the name of `greeting` for `x`, and the name of `food` for `y`.

```
    if(x=='hi') {
        alert($array.greeting); // alert('greeting');
    }
    if(y=='pizza') {
        alert($array.food); // alert('food');
    }
```

In which way would this work better, in Javascript or jQuery, how so?

Comment: in javascript one = is assignation == or ==== is condition evaluation

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Also, why are you creating your objects in quotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size/structure of your object containing the arrays, you can simply iterate over they keys and find the key whose value (array) contains the value you are looking for. Here's how it would look.

```js
var $arrays = {
  "greeting": ['hello', 'hi'],
  "food": ['pizza', 'cookie']
};
var x = 'hi',
    y = 'pizza';

function getContainerName(value) {
  return Object.keys($arrays).find(function(key) {
    return $arrays[key].find(function(elem) {
      return elem === value;
    })
  });
}

console.log(getContainerName(x));
console.log(getContainerName(y));
```

**Alternatively in ES6 syntax**

`return Object.keys($arrays).find(key => $arrays[key].find(elem => elem === value));`

---

**UPDATE** - To make this search for an array of values and find the name of the property that contains *all* values in the array, you can use the `.every()` function in conjunction with the above code, like so:

```js
y = ['chips', 'pizza'], x = {"food":['banana', 'carrot', 'pizza', 'wheat', 'chips']};

function getContainerName(obj, values) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(function(key) {
    return values.every(value => obj[key].find(function(elem) {
      return elem === value;
    }));
  });
}

console.log(getContainerName(x, y));
```

Comment: A little late, would this work if x was an array where it needs to find a specific value in that array? eg. `y = ['chips', 'pizza'], x = {"food":['banana', 'carrot', 'pizza', 'wheat', 'chips']}` So, it would need to find chips and pizza, in the x array, so `console.log(getContainerName(x))` would return `food`?

Comment: @Ackados Updated. Take a look

Comment: Awesome, last thing, I tried modifying it for there to be more than just `food` in the array, and added `greetings`, but I get undefined error when I change `pizza` in y to `hi`. https://jsfiddle.net/u1zLm71f/

Comment: @Ackados Well, that changes the problem more than you might think. You should open up a new question and I can answer it there.

Comment: Link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087998/getting-name-from-nesting-arrays-from-matching-arrays