# Getting name from nesting arrays from matching arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, properties

I have some arrays, and if they contain similar values, I would like to return the name of those arrays.

```
    var x = {
      "food": ['bacon', 'cheese', 'bread', 'tomato'],
      "utilities": ['plates', 'forks', 'spatulas'],
      "guests": ['john', 'matt', 'bill']
    },
    y = ['bacon', 'tomato', 'forks'];
```

I have my variable `x`, and it has multiple arrays, with a name either `food`, or `utilities`, or `guests`. All that `y` contains, is some values that are the same within some of those arrays in the variable of `x`.  I need to return the name of the arrays that contain `bacon`,`tomato`, and `forks` in their arrays. So for this example, I need to return: `["food", "utilities"]`.

```
    function getContainerName(obj, values) {
      return Object.keys(obj).find(function(key) {
        return values.every(value => obj[key].find(function(elem) {
          return elem === value;
        }));
      });
    }
    console.log(getContainerName(x, y));
```

When throwing them through this function, I get an error `*********`. How may I go and get a returned array of `["food", "utilities"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `reduce()` on the `Object.keys` will do the job

```js
var x = {
    "food": ['bacon', 'cheese', 'bread', 'tomato'],
    "utilities": ['plates', 'forks', 'spatulas'],
    "guests": ['john', 'matt', 'bill']
  },
  y = ['bacon', 'tomato', 'forks'];

let res = Object.keys(x).reduce((a, b) => {
  if (x[b].some(v => y.includes(v))) a.push(b);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

For your comment - with var and normal function:

```
var res = Object.keys(x).reduce(function (a, b) {
    if (x[b].some(function (v) {
            return y.indexOf(v) !== -1;
        })) a.push(b);
    return a;
}, []);
```

Comment: I would do an `&& !a.includes(b)` check before pushing to `a` - else it will contains dups

Comment: Good thought @tymeJV, but as an object key is unique by definition and some stops at the first hit, I don't think there's a possible duplication. Can you say in which scenario it could happen?

Comment: Ahh yeah, nvm - it's looping the keys. It would only happen if you looped `y` first - nvm :)

Comment: Works great, I have not used `let` before, can I easily replace that with `function()`?

Comment: @Ackados `let` is a replacement for `var`, you can replace it if you intend to use that in a modern browser or you use a transpiler. You can replace the arrow function with `function()` though. Edited the answer to use a normal function and var

Comment: Nice approach, using `.reduce()`.

Comment: @baao I forget to mention that, it's better to use `.indexOf` than `.includes` because  `.includes` is not supported in all browsers. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array of [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) using a map of the `y` array, and [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var x = {
  "food": ['bacon', 'cheese', 'bread', 'tomato'],
  "utilities": ['plates', 'forks', 'spatulas'],
  "guests": ['john', 'matt', 'bill']
};
var y = ['bacon', 'tomato', 'forks'];
var yMap = y.reduce(function(o, v) { // create a map to save iteration of y on each comparsion
  o[v] = true;

  return o;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(x).filter(function(key) { // filter the keys
  return x[key].some(function(v) { // keep the key, if at least one item of the array is in the map
    return yMap[v];
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

And the ES6 version using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const x = {
  "food": ['bacon', 'cheese', 'bread', 'tomato'],
  "utilities": ['plates', 'forks', 'spatulas'],
  "guests": ['john', 'matt', 'bill']
};
const y = ['bacon', 'tomato', 'forks'];
const ySet = new Set(y);

const result = Object.keys(x).filter((key) => x[key].some((item) => ySet.has(item)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **[.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** methods with `Object.keys()`:

```
function getContainerName(obj, values) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
    return y.some(function(v){
      return obj[key].indexOf(v) !== -1;
    })
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var x = {
    "food": ['bacon', 'cheese', 'bread', 'tomato'],
    "utilities": ['plates', 'forks', 'spatulas'],
    "guests": ['john', 'matt', 'bill']
  },
  y = ['bacon', 'tomato', 'forks'];


function getContainerName(obj, values) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
    return y.some(function(v){
      return obj[key].indexOf(v) !== -1;
    })
  });
}
console.log(getContainerName(x, y));
```

Comment: If I added the code correctly, this one resulted in faster speeds. https://jsperf.com/faster-array-naming

Comment: @Ackados I think that's because this one has fewer instructions than the other ones, but they are just different ways to solve the problem, and choosing one of them depends on the situation, and wether you worry or not about **performance** or **readability**.